Changes in system-generated Appsheet views do not have an effect
) I have a table (Google Sheet) with many columns/virtual columns. Since recently changes in the system generated detail and form views are not reflected in the app anymore. Even when I add another column in the table I can see it in the data definition and in the detail/form views, but not in the app. The column is editable. Also, changing the column order in the detail/form views doesn't have an effect. All other tables (Google Sheets) work fine.

found the reason, i was still using the detail view of the original table while I was actually using the slice
